# If $\{a,b,c\}$ is a basis for $\Bbb R^3$, is $\{a+b,b-c,c-a\}$ is also a basis for $\Bbb R^3?$

Tags: linear-algebra, change-of-basis

If $\{a,b,c\}$ is a basis for $\Bbb R^3$, is $\{a+b,b-c,c-a\}$ is also a basis for $\Bbb R^3?$

---

What I thought was to look at the standard basis:
$$a = (1,0,0)$$
$$b = (0,1,0)$$
$$c = (0,0,1)$$

For this basis we get: 
$$a+b = (1,1,0)$$
$$b-c = (0,1,-1)$$
$$c-a = (-1,0,1)$$

To check if the new vectors are linear independent, put them as rows in a matrix and rank, you get: 
$$\begin{bmatrix}1&1&0\\0&1&-1\\0&0&2\end{bmatrix}$$

Namely, the vectors are linear independent.

Is it true to conclude from this basis, the standard basis, for all the bases in $\Bbb R^3$ regarding the question above?

Comment: You tried to prove a general statement by providing an explicit example. While you can *disprove* general statements by counterexample, you can't prove by example.

Comment: I know that, this is not my question, i ask if by proving for the standard basis we can conclude to any other basis, because with the standard basis we can represent any other basis by linear combination of the standard basis vectors, therfore, proving for the stadard basis will prove for other bases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is enough to check that the matrix
$$
C = \begin{bmatrix}1&1&0\\0&1&-1\\-1&0&1\end{bmatrix}
$$ has linearly independent columns/rows. But the reason why this works **even though you are just checking a special case** is as follows:

To get the new set of vectors $\{a + b, b - c, c - a\}$ from your original basis $\{a, b, c\}$, you can write the basis vectors $a, b, c$ as $1 \times 3$ row vectors and stack them on top of each other to get a $3 \times 3$ matrix:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\\c\end{bmatrix}
$$ It looks like a column vector but each row is whole vector so you have a matrix but matrix-matrix multiplication is nice so that you can pretend like it is a column vector when you multiply $C$ to it:
$$
C \begin{bmatrix}a\\b\\c\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}1&1&0\\0&1&-1\\-1&0&1\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}a\\b\\c\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}a + b\\b - c\\c - a\end{bmatrix}
$$ Well you get your new basis stacked on top of one another as a matrix. Now you know that the matrix $\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\\c\end{bmatrix}$ has linearly independent rows because the rows form a basis. Also you have already checked that $C$ has linearly independent rows. Thus their product $\begin{bmatrix}a + b\\b - c\\c - a\end{bmatrix}$ must also have linearly independent rows i.e. your new set of vectors is a basis.

Comment: Ok by the idea that if A,B are square matrices: AB is linear independent if and only if A is linear idependent and B is linear independent. Yes, i think i understand, so it holds, thank you. Do you see any other smater, or more general way for the solution?

Comment: Yes that is the idea I implicitly used. The way you used i.e. checking only the special case when $a, b, c$ are standard basis vectors always works so you can keep doing that for problems like this.

Answer (score 1):

I don't entirely understand what you mean in your last paragraph, and your matrix really ought to be
$$
\begin{bmatrix}1&1&0\\0&1&-1\\-1&0&1\end{bmatrix}
$$
However, it seems you have actually taken this matrix, then applied a couple of row operations to get the upper triangular matrix that you have.

And yes, that is the standard way of checking that a set of vectors is a basis: Take your set of vectors, expressed in any convenient basis (in this case, the basis consisting of $(a,b,c)$ is very convenient), as the rows (or more conventionally columns) of a matrix and check that the determinant is non-zero. In this case the determinant of your upper triangular matrix is clearly $2$, which is non-zero.

The standard basis is irrelevant in this particular problem. In the basis given by $(a,b,c)$, the vectors $a,b$ and $c$ are indeed given by the coordinates you have listed, which means that $a+b, b-c$ and $c-a$ are also given by the coordinates you have found, and we can use the matrix method.

Comment: By "the coordinates" for $(a,b,c)$ you mean the standard basis? how do you know that? it could be any basis. 
i took the standard basis only for convinient, and asked if by proving for him, knowing that any other basis could be represent as linear combination of the standard basis,  will be sufficient for the general case.

Comment: @Alon Did you read my final paragraph? We don't care about the standard basis. We have a basis given to us, so we use that.

Comment: So i think i dont understand your answer.

Comment: @Alon The vectors $a,b$ and $c$ form a basis. In this basis, what are the coordinates of $a,b$ and $c$?

Comment: I dont know, this is a bit problemetic area i dont fully understand (even though i have read about coordinates from several sources).

Comment: @Alon Then it's high time that you read up and reflect on what coordinates _actually_ mean, in terms of a basis. When I say "the vector $v$ has coordinates $(1,2,3)$", can you rephrase that statement to say something about the relationship between $v$ and whatever basis I'm using?

Comment: Let $B = \{b_1,b_2,b_3\}$ be an ordered basis. So: 
$v = 1*b_1+2*b_2+3*b_3?$

Comment: @Alon Exactly! So, if $\{a,b,c\}$ is our ordered basis, what are the coordinates of $a$? Of $b$? Of $c$?

Comment: I would say $(1,0,0)$ for $a$, $(0,1,0)$ for $b$ and $(0,0,1)$ for $c$.

Comment: @Alon Exactly! And at this stage, you are ready to solve the problem in general, not just for when $\{a,b,c\}$ happens to be the standard basis. Do it just the way you have already done, but make it clear that all coordinates are with respect to the basis $\{a,b,c\}$ instead of the standard basis. None of the numbers and none of the calculations change. This is what I'm trying to say in my answer.

Comment: So we take the coordinates of the basis and get a matrix that represents the maniulation on the coordinates and say that the new coordinates are linear independent so the new group is independent and we base this on what sentence?

Comment: @Alon We take the basis $\{a,b,c\}$, and express $a+b, b-c$ and $c-a$ with respect to this basis. Then we get the coordinates that you have written in your post, with $a+b=(1,1,0)$, and so on. Then we construct a matrix using these three sets of coordinates as the rows, and we get the matrix I wrote in my answer. Then we check the determinant of that matrix, and we see that that determinant is non-zero, so its rows are linearly independent. So $a+b, b-c$ and $c-a$ are linearly independent.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much for the patience.